# Oracle query to Exclude weekends, and 6PM to 9PM

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I am trying to achieve a query that returns the time difference between two dates excluding weekends(Saturday and Sunday) and excluding time (6 pm-9 am).
For now, I have a function that is excluding the weekends, But I am unable to exclude time from the query. Can anyone help with this?
The article from which I take help is [this](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2557204/function-to-calculate-business-minutes-between-two-dates)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_bus_minutes_between(

                                   p_start_date DATE,

                                   p_end_date DATE

                                  )

    RETURN NUMBER
    DETERMINISTIC -- ***** Can't hurt
    IS
        days_diff     NUMBER  := 0;
        end_date      DATE    := p_end_date;
        minutes_diff  NUMBER;
        start_date    DATE    := p_start_date;
        weeks_diff    NUMBER;
BEGIN
    IF  start_date <= end_date
    THEN
        --  Move start_date and end_date away from weekends
        IF  start_date > TRUNC (start_date, 'IW') + 5
        THEN     -- Use next Monday for start_date
            start_date := TRUNC (start_date, 'IW') + 7;
        END IF;

        IF  end_date > TRUNC (end_date, 'IW') + 5
        THEN     -- Use Friday quitting time
            end_date := TRUNC (end_date, 'IW') + 4 + (16.5 / 24);
        END IF;

       -- Move start_date into the same weeek as end_date
       -- (Remember how many weeks we had to move it)
       weeks_diff := ( TRUNC (end_date,   'IW')
                     - TRUNC (start_date, 'IW')
                     ) / 7;
       IF  weeks_diff > 0
       THEN
           start_date := start_date + (7 * weeks_diff);
       END IF;

       -- Make start_date the same day as end_date
       -- (Remember how many days we had to move it)
       days_diff := TRUNC (end_date) - TRUNC (start_date);
       IF  days_diff > 0
       THEN
           start_date := start_date + days_diff;
       END IF;

       -- Move start_date up to starting time
       start_date := GREATEST ( start_date
                              , TRUNC (start_date) + (8.75 / 24)
                              );

       -- Move end_date back to quitting time
       end_date := LEAST ( end_date
                         , TRUNC (end_date) + ( CASE
                                                    WHEN  TO_CHAR ( end_date
                                                                  , 'DY'
                                                                  , 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'
                                                                  ) = 'FRI'
                                                    THEN  16.5
                                                    ELSE  17
                                                END
                                              / 24
                                              )
                         );

         minutes_diff := ( GREATEST ( 0
                                    , end_date - start_date
                                    )
                         * 24 * 60
                         )
                     +  (days_diff * 495)     --  495 minutes per full day (Mon.-Thu.)
                     +  (weeks_diff * 2445);  -- 2445 minutes per full week
    ELSIF  start_date > end_date
    THEN
        minutes_diff := -get_bus_minutes_between (end_date, start_date);
    ELSE    -- One of the arguments was NULL
        minutes_diff := NULL;
    END IF;

   RETURN  ROUND(minutes_diff);
END  get_bus_minutes_between;
```

Comment: A couple things to try:  Verify that the `DATE` values being passed into your function have a time component.  Lots of databases _applications_ often discard the time portion on inserts.  Second thing:  I would try setting up a test `SELECT` query with each piece of logic set up as an output, to see if each "step of the way" in your logic is doing what is expected.  And also verify the `TRUNC` function is returning what you are expecting; see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html#GUID-8E10AB76-21DA-490F-A389-023B648DDEF8

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936398/calculate-hours-based-on-business-hours-in-oracle-sql/41937356#41937356

Answer (score 0):

You can directly calculate the difference in days (adapted from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44203787/1509264)):

```sql
SELECT start_date,
       end_date,
       ROUND(
         (
           -- Calculate the full weeks difference from the start of ISO weeks.
           ( TRUNC( end_date, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) ) * (9/24) * (5/7)
           -- Add the full days for the final week.
           + LEAST( TRUNC( end_date ) - TRUNC( end_date, 'IW' ), 5 ) * (9/24)
           -- Subtract the full days from the days of the week before the start date.
           - LEAST( TRUNC( start_date ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ), 5 ) * (9/24)
           -- Add the hours of the final day
           + LEAST( GREATEST( end_date - TRUNC( end_date ) - 9/24, 0 ), 9/24 )
           -- Subtract the hours of the day before the range starts.
           - LEAST( GREATEST( start_date - TRUNC( start_date ) - 9/24, 0 ), 9/24 )
         )
         -- Multiply to give minutes rather than fractions of full days.
         * 24 * 60
       ) AS work_day_mins_diff
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( start_date, end_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-12-30' + INTERVAL '00' HOUR, DATE '2020-12-30' + INTERVAL '12' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-30' + INTERVAL '18' HOUR, DATE '2020-12-30' + INTERVAL '20' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-30' + INTERVAL '17:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2020-12-30' + INTERVAL '21:30' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01' + INTERVAL '00' HOUR, DATE '2021-01-04' + INTERVAL '00' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-02' + INTERVAL '00' HOUR, DATE '2021-01-04' + INTERVAL '00' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-28' + INTERVAL '00' HOUR, DATE '2021-01-04' + INTERVAL '00' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-28' + INTERVAL '00' HOUR, DATE '2020-12-29' + INTERVAL '00' HOUR FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

*(Using `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS (DY)';`)*

> ```
> START_DATE                | END_DATE                  | WORK_DAY_MINS_DIFF
> :------------------------ | :------------------------ | -----------------:
> 2020-12-30 00:00:00 (WED) | 2020-12-30 12:00:00 (WED) |                180
> 2020-12-30 18:00:00 (WED) | 2020-12-30 20:00:00 (WED) |                  0
> 2020-12-30 17:30:00 (WED) | 2020-12-30 21:30:00 (WED) |                 30
> 2021-01-01 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 (MON) |                540
> 2021-01-02 00:00:00 (SAT) | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 (MON) |                  0
> 2020-12-28 00:00:00 (MON) | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 (MON) |               2700
> 2020-12-28 00:00:00 (MON) | 2020-12-29 00:00:00 (TUE) |                540
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a0d01c49751eca17a57b76fdf54d592a)*