# Calculating passed service hours for open tickets (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to calculate the time that has passed since a service request has been logged (service time), based on service hours.

Start time is the time the ticket has been logged (date_logged), end time would be either the current time for open tickets or the date_closed for closed tickets.

Service hours are:

- Monday to Thursday 07:00 - 16:30
- Friday 07:00 - 13:00

So it should look something like this (minus the "current datetime" column, that's just for context):

| Ticket-Nr. | date_logged | service time [hh:mm] | current datetime | date_closed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 06.01.21 11:30:52 | 62:33 | 14.01.2021 12:03 |  |
| 8912345 | 13.01.21 09:14:16 | 12:19 | 14.01.2021 12:03 |  |
| 6789012 | 14.01.21 10:48:01 | 00:28 | 14.01.2021 12:03 | 14.01.21 11:40 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I can't say yet whether public holidays have to be included or not, so we can ignore those for now.

I'm thankful for any help whatsoever!

Comment: Maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936398/calculate-hours-based-on-business-hours-in-oracle-sql/41937356#41937356 Perhaps you have to adapt the interval from 1 hour to 5 minutes or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the amount of time (adapted from my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65514153/1509264) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41936969/1509264)):

```sql
SELECT ticket_nr,
       date_logged,
       current_datetime,
       date_closed,
       TO_CHAR( FLOOR( service_time_seconds / 60 / 60 ), 'FM9990' )
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR( MOD( FLOOR( service_time_seconds / 60 ), 60 ), 'FM00' )
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR( MOD( service_time_seconds, 60 ), 'FM00' )
         AS "SERVICE_TIME HH:MM:SS"
FROM   (
SELECT ticket_nr,
       date_logged,
       SYSDATE AS current_datetime,
       date_closed,
       ROUND(
         (
           -- Calculate the full weeks difference from the start of ISO weeks.
           ( 
             TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ), 'IW' )
             - TRUNC( date_logged, 'IW' )
           ) * (9.5*4+6)/(7*24)
           -- Add the hours for the full days for the final week.
           + DECODE(
               TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ) )
               - TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ), 'IW' ),
               0,  0.0,
               1,  9.5,
               2, 19.0,
               3, 28.5,
               4, 38.0,
                  44.0
             ) / 24
           -- Subtract the hours for the full days from the days of the week
           -- before the date logged.
           - DECODE(
               TRUNC( date_logged )
               - TRUNC( date_logged, 'IW' ),
               0,  0.0,
               1,  9.5,
               2, 19.0,
               3, 28.5,
               4, 38.0,
                  44.0
             ) / 24
           -- Add the hours of the final day
           + LEAST(
               GREATEST(
                 COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE )
                 - ( TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ) )
                     + INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE
                   ),
                 0
               ),
               DECODE(
                 TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ) )
                 - TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ), 'IW' ),
                 0, 9.5,
                 1, 9.5,
                 2, 9.5,
                 3, 9.5,
                 4, 6.0,
                    0.0
               ) / 24
             )
           -- Subtract the hours of the day before the range starts.
           - LEAST(
               GREATEST(
                 date_logged
                 - ( TRUNC( date_logged ) + INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE ),
                 0
               ),
               DECODE(
                 TRUNC( date_logged )
                 - TRUNC( date_logged, 'IW' ),
                 0, 9.5,
                 1, 9.5,
                 2, 9.5,
                 3, 9.5,
                 4, 6.0,
                    0.0
               ) / 24
             )
         )
         -- Multiply to give seconds rather than fractions of full days.
         * 24 * 60 * 60
       ) AS service_time_seconds
FROM   table_name
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Ticket_Nr, date_logged, date_closed ) AS
SELECT 1234567, DATE '2021-01-06' + INTERVAL '11:30:52' HOUR TO SECOND, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8912345, DATE '2021-01-13' + INTERVAL '09:14:16' HOUR TO SECOND, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6789012, DATE '2021-01-14' + INTERVAL '10:48:28' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2021-01-21' + INTERVAL '11:40:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT       1, DATE '2021-01-07' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2021-01-14' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT       2, DATE '2021-01-07' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2021-01-08' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT       3, DATE '2021-01-08' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2021-01-09' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT       4, DATE '2021-01-09' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2021-01-10' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL
```

Outputs (where `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS (DY)`):

> ```
> TICKET_NR | DATE_LOGGED               | CURRENT_DATETIME          | DATE_CLOSED               | SERVICE_TIME HH:MM:SS
> --------: | :------------------------ | :------------------------ | :------------------------ | :--------------------
>   1234567 | 2021-01-06 11:30:52 (WED) | 2021-01-14 12:36:54 (THU) | null                      | 54:36:02             
>   8912345 | 2021-01-13 09:14:16 (WED) | 2021-01-14 12:36:54 (THU) | null                      | 12:52:38             
>   6789012 | 2021-01-14 10:48:28 (THU) | 2021-01-14 12:36:54 (THU) | 2021-01-21 11:40:00 (THU) | 44:51:32             
>         1 | 2021-01-07 07:00:00 (THU) | 2021-01-14 12:36:54 (THU) | 2021-01-14 07:00:00 (THU) | 44:00:00             
>         2 | 2021-01-07 07:00:00 (THU) | 2021-01-14 12:36:54 (THU) | 2021-01-08 07:00:00 (FRI) | 9:30:00              
>         3 | 2021-01-08 07:00:00 (FRI) | 2021-01-14 12:36:54 (THU) | 2021-01-09 07:00:00 (SAT) | 6:00:00              
>         4 | 2021-01-09 07:00:00 (SAT) | 2021-01-14 12:36:54 (THU) | 2021-01-10 07:00:00 (SUN) | 0:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=85102e97534e02f8f51d6d2dc92a3dba)*

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response @MT0 ! It worked, you are a life saver. :) One follow up question tho: I've just now noticed that there seem to be variations regarding the service hours. It seems to be dependent on the department that the ticket belongs to (dept. A1, A2, A3, B, C have the same service hours as well as dept. C5, G, T and Q, etc.). Is there a way to include this? (It looks like the same thing goes for service free days/holidays)

Comment: @Acinogara Ask [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for your follow-up (as it is probably going to be significantly different to this answer and it too complicated to understand your requirements from a short comment) and make sure you include a [MRE] with: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for your tables; DML (`INSERT`) statements for your sample data; and a complete description of the problem including how the hours change for each department.