# Calculating passed service hours

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to calculate the time that has passed since a service request has been logged (service time), based on service hours.

Start time is the time the ticket has been logged (date_logged), end time would be either the current time (for open tickets) or the date_closed for closed tickets.

Service hours vary depending on the department the ticket was assigned to, as listed in the example below (all the times and dates in my table have the data type ***datetime***):

| Ticket-Nr. | Department | date_logged | date_closed | start_mon | end_mon | start_tue | end_tue | start_wed | end_wed | start_trs | end_trs | start_fri | end_fri | start_sat | end_sat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | A | 06.01.21 11:30:52 |  | 01.01.2001 07:30 | 01.01.2001 16:45 | 01.01.2001 07:30 | 01.01.2001 16:45 | 01.01.2001 07:30 | 01.01.2001 16:45 | 01.01.2001 07:30 | 01.01.2001 16:45 | 01.01.2001 07:30 | 01.01.2001 13:00 |  |  |
| 8912345 | B | 13.01.21 09:14:16 |  | 01.01.2001 07:00 | 01.01.2001 16:30 | 01.01.2001 07:00 | 01.01.2001 16:30 | 01.01.2001 07:00 | 01.01.2001 16:30 | 01.01.2001 07:00 | 01.01.2001 16:30 | 01.01.2001 07:00 | 01.01.2001 16:30 | 01.01.2001 07:00 | 01.01.2001 15:00 |
| 6789012 | C | 14.01.21 10:48:01 | 14.01.21 11:40 | 01.01.2001 07:00 | 01.01.2001 16:30 | 01.01.2001 07:00 | 01.01.2001 16:30 | 01.01.2001 07:00 | 01.01.2001 16:30 | 01.01.2001 07:00 | 01.01.2001 16:30 | 01.01.2001 07:00 | 01.01.2001 16:30 | 01.01.2001 07:00 | 01.01.2001 15:00 |
| 3456789 | D | 15.01.2021 09:41:00 |  | 01.01.2001 08:00 | 01.01.2001 15:00 | 01.01.2001 08:00 | 01.01.2001 15:00 | 01.01.2001 08:00 | 01.01.2001 15:00 | 01.01.2001 08:00 | 01.01.2001 15:00 | 01.01.2001 08:00 | 01.01.2001 13:00 |  |  |
| 0123456 | B | 02.01.2021 13:12:00 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The result should look something like this (minus the "current datetime" column, that's just for context):

| Ticket-Nr. | department | date_logged | service time [hh:mm] | current datetime | date_closed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | A | 06.01.21 11:30:52 | 62:33 | 14.01.2021 12:03 |  |
| 8912345 | B | 13.01.21 09:14:16 | 12:19 | 14.01.2021 12:03 |  |
| 6789012 | C | 14.01.21 10:48:01 | 00:28 | 14.01.2021 12:03 | 14.01.21 11:40 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Public holidays have to be included for department A, B and D.

Comment: Given the complexity of your business rules, I would suggest that you create table with one row per day and department, specifying the working hours on that day.

Comment: @GordonLinoff good point! I hope it's more clearly now.

Comment: If you don't have too many departments then you can still use my approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936398/calculate-hours-based-on-business-hours-in-oracle-sql/41937356#41937356

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement or your table and DML (`INSERT`) statements for your sample data. While a table may look nice it is not helpful to people answering the question to have to take all the data out of the table into `INSERT` statements and to have to guess at your data types.

Comment: Also, assuming that a department always has the same service hours for all tickets, it looks like your update violates 3rd normal form and you are going to get a lot of duplication for the start/end times in each row. It would be better to return to your previous structure and have a separate table of hours.

Comment: I can't return to another structure, because this the structure I have to work with. I'm not allowed to alter existing tables or create new ones (I only have the permission to read on this database). Also it seems like the service hours can occasionally vary within a department and apparently it's possible that it changed over the years, so I would probably try to determine the service time on ticket-level, since the service start- and end-time per weekday is specified for every ticket anyway (all this turned out a lot more complex than I first anticipated).

Answer (score 1):

You can directly calculate the hours (extending your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65718540/1509264)):

```sql
SELECT ticket_nr,
       department,
       date_logged,
       current_datetime,
       date_closed,
       TO_CHAR( FLOOR( service_time_seconds / 60 / 60 ), 'FM99990' )
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR( MOD( FLOOR( service_time_seconds / 60 ), 60 ), 'FM00' )
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR( MOD( service_time_seconds, 60 ), 'FM00' )
         AS "SERVICE_TIME HH:MM:SS"
FROM   (
SELECT t.ticket_nr,
       t.department,
       t.date_logged,
       SYSDATE AS current_datetime,
       t.date_closed,
       ROUND(
         (
           -- Calculate the full weeks difference from the start of ISO weeks.
           ( 
             TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ), 'IW' )
             - TRUNC( date_logged, 'IW' )
           ) * ( s.hours_mon
                 + s.hours_tue
                 + s.hours_wed
                 + s.hours_thu
                 + s.hours_fri
                 + s.hours_sat
                 + s.hours_sun ) / (7*24)
           -- Add the hours for the full days for the final week.
           + DECODE(
               TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ) )
               - TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ), 'IW' ),
               0,  0.0,
               1, s.hours_mon,
               2, s.hours_mon + s.hours_tue,
               3, s.hours_mon + s.hours_tue + s.hours_wed,
               4, s.hours_mon + s.hours_tue + s.hours_wed + s.hours_thu,
               5, s.hours_mon + s.hours_tue + s.hours_wed + s.hours_thu + s.hours_fri,
               6, s.hours_mon + s.hours_tue + s.hours_wed + s.hours_thu + s.hours_fri + s.hours_sat
             ) / 24
           -- Subtract the hours for the full days from the days of the week
           -- before the date logged.
           - DECODE(
               TRUNC( date_logged ) - TRUNC( date_logged, 'IW' ),
               0,  0.0,
               1, s.hours_mon,
               2, s.hours_mon + s.hours_tue,
               3, s.hours_mon + s.hours_tue + s.hours_wed,
               4, s.hours_mon + s.hours_tue + s.hours_wed + s.hours_thu,
               5, s.hours_mon + s.hours_tue + s.hours_wed + s.hours_thu + s.hours_fri,
               6, s.hours_mon + s.hours_tue + s.hours_wed + s.hours_thu + s.hours_fri + s.hours_sat
             ) / 24
           -- Add the hours of the final day
           + COALESCE(
               GREATEST(
                 LEAST(
                   COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ),
                   TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ) )
                   + DECODE(
                       TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ) )
                       - TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ), 'IW' ),
                       0, s.end_mon,
                       1, s.end_tue,
                       2, s.end_wed,
                       3, s.end_thu,
                       4, s.end_fri,
                       5, s.end_sat,
                       6, s.end_sun
                     )
                 )
                 -
                 (
                   TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ) )
                   + DECODE(
                       TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ) )
                       - TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ), 'IW' ),
                       0, s.start_mon,
                       1, s.start_tue,
                       2, s.start_wed,
                       3, s.start_thu,
                       4, s.start_fri,
                       5, s.start_sat,
                       6, s.start_sun
                     )
                   ),
                 0
               ) / 24,
               0
             )
           -- Subtract the hours of the day before the range starts.
           + COALESCE(
               GREATEST(
                 LEAST(
                   date_logged,
                   date_logged
                   + DECODE(
                       TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ) )
                       - TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ), 'IW' ),
                       0, s.end_mon,
                       1, s.end_tue,
                       2, s.end_wed,
                       3, s.end_thu,
                       4, s.end_fri,
                       5, s.end_sat,
                       6, s.end_sun
                     )
                 )
                 -
                 (
                   date_logged
                   + DECODE(
                       TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ) )
                       - TRUNC( COALESCE( date_closed, SYSDATE ), 'IW' ),
                       0, s.start_mon,
                       1, s.start_tue,
                       2, s.start_wed,
                       3, s.start_thu,
                       4, s.start_fri,
                       5, s.start_sat,
                       6, s.start_sun
                     )
                   ),
                 0
               ) / 24,
               0
             )
         )
         -- Multiply to give seconds rather than fractions of full days.
         * 24 * 60 * 60
       ) AS service_time_seconds
FROM   table_name t
       INNER JOIN service_hours s
       ON ( s.department = t.department )
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Ticket_Nr, department, date_logged, date_closed ) AS
SELECT 1234567, 'A', DATE '2021-01-06' + INTERVAL '11:30:52' HOUR TO SECOND, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8912345, 'B', DATE '2021-01-13' + INTERVAL '09:14:16' HOUR TO SECOND, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6789012, 'C', DATE '2021-01-14' + INTERVAL '10:48:28' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2021-01-21' + INTERVAL '11:40:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT       1, 'D', DATE '2021-01-07' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2021-01-14' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT       2, 'A', DATE '2021-01-07' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2021-01-08' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT       3, 'A', DATE '2021-01-08' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2021-01-09' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT       4, 'A', DATE '2021-01-09' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2021-01-10' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT       5, 'B', DATE '2021-01-09' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2021-01-10' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE service_hours (
  Department VARCHAR2(5)
             CONSTRAINT service_hours__department__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  start_mon  INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  end_mon    INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  hours_mon  NUMBER
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
               COALESCE(
                 ( DATE '1970-01-01' + end_mon ) - ( DATE '1970-01-01' + start_mon ),
                 0
               ) * 24
             ),
  start_tue  INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  end_tue    INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  hours_tue  NUMBER
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
               COALESCE(
                 ( DATE '1970-01-01' + end_tue ) - ( DATE '1970-01-01' + start_tue ),
                 0
               ) * 24
             ),
  start_wed  INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  end_wed    INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  hours_wed  NUMBER
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
               COALESCE(
                 ( DATE '1970-01-01' + end_wed ) - ( DATE '1970-01-01' + start_wed ),
                 0
               ) * 24
             ),
  start_thu  INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  end_thu    INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  hours_thu  NUMBER
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
               COALESCE(
                 ( DATE '1970-01-01' + end_thu ) - ( DATE '1970-01-01' + start_thu ),
                 0
               ) * 24
             ),
  start_fri  INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  end_fri    INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  hours_fri  NUMBER
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
               COALESCE(
                 ( DATE '1970-01-01' + end_fri ) - ( DATE '1970-01-01' + start_fri ),
                 0
               ) * 24
             ),
  start_sat  INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  end_sat    INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  hours_sat  NUMBER
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
               COALESCE(
                 ( DATE '1970-01-01' + end_sat ) - ( DATE '1970-01-01' + start_sat ),
                 0
               ) * 24
             ),
  start_sun  INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  end_sun    INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  hours_sun  NUMBER
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
               COALESCE(
                 ( DATE '1970-01-01' + end_sun ) - ( DATE '1970-01-01' + start_sun ),
                 0
               ) * 24
             )
);

INSERT INTO service_hours (
  Department, 
  start_mon, end_mon,
  start_tue, end_tue,
  start_wed, end_wed,
  start_thu, end_thu,
  start_fri, end_fri,
  start_sat, end_sat,
  start_sun, end_sun
)
SELECT 'A',
       INTERVAL '07:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:45' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:45' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:45' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:45' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '13:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       NULL, NULL,
       NULL, NULL
FROM   DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',
       INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:30' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:30' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:30' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:30' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:30' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '15:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       NULL, NULL
FROM   DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',
       INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:30' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:30' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:30' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:30' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '16:30' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '15:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       NULL, NULL
FROM   DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D',
       INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '15:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '15:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '15:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '15:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '15:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       NULL, NULL,
       NULL, NULL
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> TICKET_NR | DEPARTMENT | DATE_LOGGED               | CURRENT_DATETIME          | DATE_CLOSED               | SERVICE_TIME HH:MM:SS
> --------: | :--------- | :------------------------ | :------------------------ | :------------------------ | :--------------------
>   1234567 | A          | 2021-01-06 11:30:52 (WED) | 2021-01-15 13:38:49 (FRI) | null                      | 61:13:45             
>   8912345 | B          | 2021-01-13 09:14:16 (WED) | 2021-01-15 13:38:49 (FRI) | null                      | 19:16:37             
>   6789012 | C          | 2021-01-14 10:48:28 (THU) | 2021-01-15 13:38:49 (FRI) | 2021-01-21 11:40:00 (THU) | 55:41:40             
>         1 | D          | 2021-01-07 07:00:00 (THU) | 2021-01-15 13:38:49 (FRI) | 2021-01-14 07:00:00 (THU) | 35:00:00             
>         2 | A          | 2021-01-07 07:00:00 (THU) | 2021-01-15 13:38:49 (FRI) | 2021-01-08 07:00:00 (FRI) | 9:15:00              
>         3 | A          | 2021-01-08 07:00:00 (FRI) | 2021-01-15 13:38:49 (FRI) | 2021-01-09 07:00:00 (SAT) | 5:30:00              
>         4 | A          | 2021-01-09 07:00:00 (SAT) | 2021-01-15 13:38:49 (FRI) | 2021-01-10 07:00:00 (SUN) | 0:00:00              
>         5 | B          | 2021-01-09 07:00:00 (SAT) | 2021-01-15 13:38:49 (FRI) | 2021-01-10 07:00:00 (SUN) | 8:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d1c166111fba74b947a967a8c2f634e7)*

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Unfortunately I realized that I've explained the table structure insufficiently... the service hours are actually in the same table as the tickets. I've edited my original question, so you have an idea of what it looks like. I tried altering your script by exchanging the s.hours_day with 24*(day_end - day_start), but I get an error, telling my that "date + date not allowed" (the day_start and day_end columns have a datetime format). Thank you again and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Acinogara Not much changes [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=81f5c63599f38db4249265d94a05fe43).