# create custom function for date difference excluding weekends and holidays in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to calculate the number of days between two dates as **decimal**, **excluding the weekends and holidays** by **using a custom function** in Oracle SQL.
There are similar questions on the site; however as I could see, none of them asks for an output as decimal using a custom function. The reason why I need a decimal is to be able to use/extract time component afterwards. If there is already a question like this, please just share the link.

Tried to write a function as below with the help of the additional content I found on the internet [thanks to the author](https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2017/03/16/oracle-calculating-business-days-between-two-dates-in-oracle/).  The inner subqueries works fine seperately, but it doesn't work as a whole function.

In brief, the idea is:

*(calculate the day difference between startdate and enddate) -> (exclude the number of weekend days between startdate and enddate) -> (exclude the number of weekends between startdate and enddate)*

When I try to save the function, it gives the error `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"`. Since I am already new in functions maybe missing something basic.

Lastly, also please let me know if you have suggestions on how to make the code more efficient.

Thanks in advance!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  NET_WORKING_DAYS (startdate IN DATE, enddate IN DATE)
RETURN NUMBER IS 
  WORKINGDAYS_BETWEEN NUMBER;
BEGIN

SELECT

    -- number of days between startdate and enddate
      (
        SELECT (TO_DATE('20160831150000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')  - TO_DATE('20160801000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') ) DAYS_BETWEEN 
        FROM DUAL
      )  
    -
    -- number of weekend days (after a given date)
      (
        SELECT COUNT(1)  WEEKEND_DAYS_BETWEEN
        FROM
        (
          SELECT
            TO_DATE('20160701000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') + SEQ as day_date,     --2016/07/01 is a constant/given date for this formula
            TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20160701000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') + SEQ , 'D') day_of_week
          FROM
            (
                SELECT ROWNUM-1 SEQ
                FROM   ( SELECT 1 FROM  DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<= 365 * 5) --5 years
            )
          ORDER BY 1
        )
        WHERE day_of_week IN (6,7) 
          AND day_date > TO_DATE('20160801000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')     --this should be replaced with startdate parameter
          AND day_date < TO_DATE('20160831000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')      --this should be replaced with enddate parameter
      )  
    -
    -- number of holidays (after a given date)
      (
        SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM HOLIDAYS
        WHERE HOLIDAY_DATE > TO_DATE('20160801000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')     --this should be replaced with startdate parameter
          AND HOLIDAY_DATE < TO_DATE('20160831000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')      --this should be replaced with enddate parameter
      )
INTO WORKINGDAYS_BETWEEN
FROM DUAL;

RETURN WORKINGDAYS_BETWEEN;
END NET_WORKING_DAYS;
```

**EDIT-1: Holidays are already defined in HOLIDAYS table in the database and for this date range from `20160801000000` to `20160831000000` , `30.06.2016` is the holiday date.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43632677/1509264

Comment: For the range 2016-08-26 08:16:39 to 2016-08-30 08:17:01, how is to the desired solution 4.00025... days? 2016-08-27 is a Saturday, 2016-08-28 is a Sunday and 2016-08-30 is a holiday. So you should have 1 full day for 2016-08-29 and then 2016-08-26 08:16:39 to 2016-08-27 00:00:00 which is 0.655 days for 1.655 working days total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use a row generator to enumerate every day to get the number of week days - it can be done using a simple calculation:

From [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43633234/1509264):

```
CREATE FUNCTION getWorkingDays (
  in_start_date IN  DATE,
  in_end_date   IN  DATE
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  p_start_date   DATE;
  p_end_date     DATE;
  p_working_days NUMBER;
  p_holiday_days NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF in_start_date IS NULL OR in_end_date IS NULL THEN
    RETURN NUll;
  END IF;

  p_start_date := LEAST( in_start_date, in_end_date );
  p_end_date   := GREATEST( in_start_date, in_end_date );

  -- 5/7 * ( Number of days between monday of the week containing the start date
  --         and monday of the week containing the end date )
  -- + LEAST( day of week for end date, 5 )
  -- - LEAST( day of week for start date, 5 )
  p_working_days := ( TRUNC( p_end_date, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( p_start_date, 'IW' ) ) * 5 / 7
                    + LEAST( p_end_date - TRUNC( p_end_date, 'IW' ), 5 )
                    - LEAST( p_start_date - TRUNC( p_start_date, 'IW' ), 5 );

  SELECT COALESCE(
           SUM(
             LEAST( p_end_date, holiday_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY )
             - GREATEST( p_start_date, holiday_date )
           ),
           0
         )
  INTO   p_holiday_days
  FROM   Holidays
  WHERE  HOLIDAY_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC( p_start_date )
                      AND     TRUNC( p_end_date )
  AND    HOLIDAY_DATE - TRUNC( HOLIDAY_DATE, 'IW' ) < 5;

  RETURN GREATEST( p_working_days - p_holiday_days, 0 );
END;
/
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.   When I run the code you shared, it only accepts this part `CREATE FUNCTION getWorkingDays (
  in_start_date IN  DATE,
  in_end_date   IN  DATE
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  p_start_date   DATE`   What can be the reason for that?

Comment: @kzmlbyrk If you are running it in SQL developer then run it as a script (using `F5`) rather than trying to run it as a statement (`Ctrl-Enter`).

Comment: I think the result will be wrong if `Holidays` table contain any weekend (for example Labor day which is always 1st of May could fall on Saturday/Sunday), i.e. it would subtract double.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Updated to add a simple filter to remove weekend holidays.

Comment: @MT0, I have tried using F5 and also tried to edit it inside the 'code' tab in functions itself but didn't work :( Any other suggestion?

Comment: @kzmlbyrk I cannot see what you are doing so it is very difficult to debug why it does not work for you but does for me. Start with a very simple function `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getWeekDays RETURN NUMBER IS BEGIN RETURN NULL; END;` and see if you can get that to compile and gradually add parts.

Comment: @MT0, it is working now!  I checked the output. There are two notes I have  1) it gives the output as integer without decimals. Is it possible to include the decimals as I mentioned above in the question?      2) For some cases (ie starttime: 20160830202143 endtime: 20160830202320) it gives negative output, (-1 in this case).     Thanks again..

Comment: @kzmlbyrk Updated

Comment: @MT0, it works as I need; many thanks for your support on this!   I have one more request: Although I will be using your solution  instead of my above try, I'd like to know what was wrong with mine. Just for understanding my mistake.

Comment: @kzmlbyrk It will double count weekend holidays; it relies on the `NLS` settings (in some locales Monday is not the first day of the week); it counts weekends and holidays as whole days, even if the date range overlaps it by a partial day; it uses lots of hard-coded dates (so is not flexible if you want to change the boundaries); and it is inefficient to use a row generator. I cannot see an obvious issue why it doesn't compile but I didn't look hard as I had an existing solution from another answer and I cannot copy/paste to my database server so I would have to type it out manually to check.

Comment: Add this code if you want to return 0 if startdate is > than end date                               
  IF in_start_date > in_end_date  THEN
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;