# different between two dates without weekend oracle function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a function but it returns wrong numbers between two dates in oracle database. Problem is when i have two dates in the same day. Function only gets you the rounded days in between as it uses the COUNT() function to count the number of business days.

How to repair this function ??

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION fn_GetBusinessDaysInterval
(
    v_Begin_Date DATE,
    v_End_Date DATE   
)
    RETURN NUMBER
AS
    v_DaysInbetween NUMBER := 0;
    v_BusDaysInbetween NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
    WITH days
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            v_Begin_Date + seq AS day_date,
            to_char(v_Begin_Date + seq , 'D') day_of_week
        FROM
        (
            SELECT ROWNUM-1 seq
            FROM   ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   dual
                     --number of rows should be exactly the number of days between begin and end dates
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (v_End_Date - v_Begin_Date) + 1
                   )
        )
        ORDER BY 1
    )
    SELECT
        v_End_Date - v_Begin_Date AS days_inbetween,
        count(1) business_days_inbetween
    INTO
        v_DaysInbetween,
        v_BusDaysInbetween        
    FROM
        days
    WHERE
        ---------------------------------------------------
        --...then exclude Sat and Sun
        ---------------------------------------------------
        days.day_of_week NOT IN (7,1)
        ---------------------------------------------------
        --...then exclude week-day holidays
        ---------------------------------------------------

        AND NOT EXISTS
            (
                SELECT SWIETO
                FROM DNI_SWIATECZNE ht
                WHERE ht.DATA = days.day_date
                --Optionally include Region!
            );        



    RETURN v_BusDaysInbetween;        
END;
```

Comment: You do not need to use an (inefficient) row generator; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44407013/1509264) shows you how you can calculate the number of week days directly from the start and end dates and then all you need to do is subtract the number of holiday dates (which you can do using aggregation on your holiday table without the need to join tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to consider the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_GETBUSINESSDAYSINTERVAL (
    V_BEGIN_DATE DATE,
    V_END_DATE DATE
) RETURN NUMBER AS
    V_DAYSINBETWEEN      NUMBER := 0;
    V_BUSDAYSINBETWEEN   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    WITH DAYS AS (
        SELECT V_BEGIN_DATE + LEVEL AS DAY_DATE,
               TO_CHAR(V_BEGIN_DATE + LEVEL, 'D') DAY_OF_WEEK
          FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ( V_END_DATE - V_BEGIN_DATE )
    )
    SELECT
        V_END_DATE - V_BEGIN_DATE AS DAYS_INBETWEEN, --total number of days in between
        SUM(CASE WHEN DAYS.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN( 7, 1 )
                 AND HT.DATA IS NULL THEN 1 END) BUSINESS_DAYS_INBETWEEN -- total number of business days inbetween
    INTO V_DAYSINBETWEEN, V_BUSDAYSINBETWEEN
    FROM DAYS LEFT
         JOIN DNI_SWIATECZNE HT ON HT.DATA = DAYS.DAY_DATE;

    RETURN COALESCE(V_BUSDAYSINBETWEEN, 0);

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
```

Comment: how to include a hours and minutes in this funtion ? This function is great but when date are eqal the same date value may return 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN days.day_of_week NOT IN (1, 7) THEN 1 END) AS days_inbetween,
    COUNT(*) AS business_days_inbetween
INTO
    v_DaysInbetween,
    v_BusDaysInbetween        
FROM
    days
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DNI_SWIATECZNE ht
                WHERE ht.DATA = days.day_date);
```

The strategy here is to query without any restriction on day in the `WHERE` clause.  We take a conditional count of non weekend days for the days in between count, and we take the full count for the number of business days.