# (Oracle 11g DB) Calculate Number of buisiness days between current time and a date while excluding holidays in a view

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

So I have this working SQL script that take a date and returns the age from current time to the given date excluding dates defined in a table called exclude dates

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROWNUM rnum
        FROM
            all_objects
        WHERE
            ROWNUM <= CAST(current_timestamp AS DATE) - to_date('&2') + 1
    )
WHERE
    to_char(to_date('&2') + rnum - 1, 'DY') NOT IN ( 'SAT', 'SUN' )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            exclude_dates
        WHERE
            no_work = trunc(to_date('&2') + rnum - 1)
    );
```

I have a table called

> TICKETS

that contains columns named

> ID, UPDATED_AT

I want to create a view that uses the above script to return

> ID, AGE

where age is the output of the script above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create custom function for date difference excluding weekends and holidays in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406680/create-custom-function-for-date-difference-excluding-weekends-and-holidays-in-or)

Answer (score 1):

You code has a few weaknesses.

- There is no need for `CAST(current_timestamp AS DATE)`.

  If you need the current `DATE` then simply use `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`
- You don't need to select from `all_objects`. Better use hierarchical query

  `SELECT LEVEL as rnum FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ...`
- Using `to_date('&2')` without a format is usually bad. Either your input value is a string, then you should include the format, e.g. `to_date('&2', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` or your input value is a `DATE`, then simply use `&2` - never use `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE`!

Final query could be this one - assuming input parameter is a `DATE` value:

```
WITH t AS (
   SELECT LEVEL as d
   FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - the_day)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS buisiness_days
FROM t
WHERE TO_CHAR(the_day + d - 1, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
   AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 'x'
        FROM exclude_dates
        WHERE no_work = TRUNC(the_day + d - 1)
        )
```

However, for me it is not clear how you want to provide this as a view! You would need to create a separate view for each input date, or at least create a new view every day.

I would suggest to create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION buisiness_days(the_date IN DATE) RETURN INTEGER AS
   ret INTEGER;
BEGIN

    WITH t AS (
       SELECT LEVEL as d
       FROM dual
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - the_date)
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS buisiness_days
    INTO ret
    FROM t
    WHERE TO_CHAR(the_date + d - 1, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
       AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 'x'
            FROM exclude_dates
            WHERE no_work = TRUNC(the_date + d - 1)
            );
    RETURN ret;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not experienced with DBs that much and i didn't understand what a hierarchical query is but it is for sure running much faster than using all_objects; worth reading about it more

I've created a function business_days and will use it in a materialized view that will refresh at midnight to calculate the age of ticket, moreover the the updated_at column is of TIMESTAMP so i am casting it to DATE then sending it to the function.

Is there a way to refresh a materialized view based on a where clause, like refresh the rows that have status of false for example only?

Comment: You can refresh a materialized view manually on demand, by schedule or after each commit (i.e. modification) on the base table. Still, your use case is not clear to me. Do you have an example? Note, a FAST REFRESH materialized view (which might be required in your case) must not contain values which are based on `SYSDATE`.

Comment: In order to cast a `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE` use `CAST(updated_at AS DATE)` instead of `TO_DATE()`

Comment: I have a tickets table, and i need to send an email once a ticket age is more than 3 days, but the age must not include holidays and weekends, also the age is equal to the date the last time the ticket was updated - the time of creation.

i have two columns, created_at and updated_at, I created a function you provided to calculate the age based on these two dates, but I think creating a view will make it slow over time when there are lots of tickets (with all_objects the query took more than 5 mins to calculate for 48000 rows), but your solution is milliseconds fast.

Comment: Maybe check also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936398/calculate-hours-based-on-business-hours-in-oracle-sql/41937356#41937356

Answer (score 0):

The function will return a list of dates between the date range you provide so the dates don't have to be stored in a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE nt_date IS TABLE OF DATE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_dates_pipelined(
  p_from IN DATE,
  p_to   IN DATE
)
  RETURN nt_date PIPELINED DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v_start DATE := TRUNC(LEAST(p_from, p_to));
  v_end   DATE := TRUNC(GREATEST(p_from, p_to));
BEGIN
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (v_start);
    EXIT WHEN v_start >= v_end;
    v_start := v_start + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END generate_dates_pipelined;
/
```

To exclude holidays you need to know what dates they fall on so there needs to be a holiday table.

```
create table holidays(
          holiday_date DATE not null,
          holiday_name VARCHAR2(20),
          constraint holidays_pk primary key (holiday_date),
          constraint is_midnight check ( holiday_date = trunc ( holiday_date ) )
        );

INSERT into holidays (HOLIDAY_DATE,HOLIDAY_NAME)
        WITH dts as (
          select to_date('25-NOV-2021 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'Thanksgiving 2021' from dual union all
          select to_date('29-NOV-2021 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'Hanukkah 2021' from dual
        )
        SELECT * from dts;
```

This query will provide the count of days between the range, number of working days and number of holidays in the range.

```
SELECT   COUNT (*)            AS total_days
,     COUNT ( CASE
              WHEN h.holiday_date IS NULL
              AND  d.column_value - TRUNC (d.column_value, 'IW') < 5
              THEN 'Business Day'
          END
        )            AS business_days
,      COUNT (h.holiday_date)    AS holidays
FROM      generate_dates_pipelined (DATE '2021-11-01', DATE '2021-11-30') d
LEFT JOIN holidays h ON h.holiday_date = d.column_value;
```

This query will provide a list of dates excluding sat, sun and holidays that fall between the range.

```
SELECT
        COLUMN_VALUE 
  FROM   
TABLE(generate_dates_pipelined(DATE '2021-11-01',
DATE '2021-11-30')) c
where 
to_char(COLUMN_VALUE, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN') 
AND NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
             FROM   holidays h
             WHERE  c.COLUMN_VALUE = h.holiday_date
           );
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to implement it and test it out, for now I'm using @wernfried-domscheit solution as I'm tight on time, really appreciate it!

Comment: A PIPELINED  looks a bit overkill to me. Simple `BULK COLLECT` would be sufficient.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit perhaps in this situation but Its nice, neat, compact and I use this function in quite a few places in several applications

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function or to use a row generator function and can calculate the number of business days:

```sql
CREATE VIEW business_day_ages (ID, AGE) AS
SELECT id,
       ( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( updated_at, 'IW' ) ) * 5 / 7
       -- Number of full weeks.
       + LEAST( SYSDATE - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ), 5 )
       -- Add part weeks at the end.
       - LEAST( updated_at - TRUNC( updated_at, 'IW' ), 5 )
       -- Subtract part weeks at the start.
       - COALESCE(
           ( SELECT SUM(
                      LEAST(no_work + INTERVAL '1' DAY, SYSDATE)
                    - GREATEST(no_work, updated_at)
                    )
             FROM   exclude_dates
             WHERE  no_work BETWEEN TRUNC(updated_at) AND SYSDATE
           ),
           0
         )
         -- Subtract the holiday days.
FROM   tickets;
```

Or, if you are not calculating using part days then you can simplify it to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW business_day_ages (ID, AGE) AS
SELECT id,
       ( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( updated_at, 'IW' ) ) * 5 / 7
       -- Number of full weeks.
       + LEAST( TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ), 5 )
       -- Add part weeks at the end.
       - LEAST( updated_at - TRUNC( updated_at, 'IW' ), 5 )
       -- Subtract part weeks at the start.
       - COALESCE(
           ( SELECT 1
             FROM   exclude_dates
             WHERE  no_work BETWEEN TRUNC(updated_at) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
           ),
           0
         )
         -- Subtract the holiday days.
FROM   tickets;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1b674e272c93218691a02bbf900c55c1)*