# Oracle query to get the number of business days between 2 dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

We are using Oracle 11.

In our CASE WHEN statement, I need to check if the number of days between the 2 dates are > 3 business days (so excluding weekends and holidays).

So, if

Date1 = 1/21/19 (Monday)

Date2 = 1/18/19 (Friday)

The number of business days in between Date1 and Date2 is 1 day, not 3 days.

```
CASE WHEN TO_DATE(SETTLEMENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE(TRADE_DATE, 
'YYYY-MM-DD')  > 3  THEN 0  --> this includes weekend and holidays
WHEN CODE = 1 THEN 1
WHEN CODE =2 THEN 2
ELSE 3
END AS MyColumn
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use a hierarchical query and can do it independent of the NLS settings using `TRUNC( date_value, 'IW' )` to find the start of the ISO week, which is always a Monday.

```
( TRUNC( end_date, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) ) * 5 / 7
```

Will find the number of working days between the start of the ISO week containing the start date and the start of the ISO week containing the end date.

Then just add the working days of the final week:

```
+ LEAST( TRUNC( end_date   ) - TRUNC( end_date,   'IW' ) + 1, 5 )
```

And subtract the days of the first ISO week before the start date:

```
- LEAST( TRUNC( start_date ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ), 5 )
```

Which when put together gives:

**Oracle Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( start_date, end_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2018-12-30' + LEVEL, DATE '2019-01-10' 
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 11
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD "("DY")"') AS start_date,

       ( TRUNC( end_date, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) ) * 5 / 7
       + LEAST( TRUNC( end_date   ) - TRUNC( end_date,   'IW' ) + 1, 5 )
       - LEAST( TRUNC( start_date ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ), 5 )
         AS Num_Week_Days
FROM   table_name;
```

**Output**:

```
START_DATE       | NUM_WEEK_DAYS
:--------------- | ------------:
2018-12-31 (MON) |             9
2019-01-01 (TUE) |             8
2019-01-02 (WED) |             7
2019-01-03 (THU) |             6
2019-01-04 (FRI) |             5
2019-01-05 (SAT) |             4
2019-01-06 (SUN) |             4
2019-01-07 (MON) |             4
2019-01-08 (TUE) |             3
2019-01-09 (WED) |             2
2019-01-10 (THU) |             1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f0c0f2e4ca649257d9439541de4a4c96)*

Comment: Thank you all for your help.
I ended up using MT0's solution. But, how do I also exclude holidays in this query ? Say I have a holiday calendar table that has column HolidayDates that contains all the holidays, for ex: 12/25/2018, 12/31/2018, etc.

Comment: @faujong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632677/function-to-get-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-excluding-holidays/43633234#43633234 If that does not answer your query then you should ask a new question as it is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create such a function which uses `conditional aggregation` as

```
SQL> alter session set NLS_TERRITORY="AMERICA"
SQL> create or replace function get_working_days( 
                                             i_settlement_date tab.settlement_date%type, 
                                             i_trade_date      tab.trade_date%type
                                           ) return pls_integer is
  o_working_days  pls_integer;                                         
begin
  select nvl(sum(case when
              to_char(trade_date + level,'Dy') in ('Sat','Sun') 
             then 0
             else 1
             end ),0)
  into o_working_days
  from tab
 where settlement_date >= trade_date
 connect by level <= i_settlement_date - i_trade_date + 1;

 return o_working_days;
end;
```

to get the working days between two date including both boundary dates.

*i.e. it returns `2` for your case including `monday` and `friday`.*

**Edit :** If you don't want to create a function, use the following query with substution variables `&i_settlement_date` and `&i_trade_date` :

```
  select nvl(sum(case when
              to_char(trade_date + level,'Dy') in ('Sat','Sun') 
             then 0
             else 1
             end ),0) as working_days
  from tab
 where settlement_date >= trade_date
 connect by level <= &i_settlement_date - &i_trade_date + 1;
```

and enter the sample values as `date'2019-01-21'` and `date'2019-01-18'` respectively, whenver prompted.

Comment: Result of `to_char(trade_date + level,'D','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')` depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY`. `'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'` has no effect for it. Use `to_char(trade_date + level,'Dy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') in ('Sat','Sun')`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ok, recalled from a former discussion that you were right about `territory` , thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Does this statement alter everyone's NLS_TERRITORY, or only my session ? Since I don't have access to create a function on Oracle, is there a way to do it without a Function ?

Comment: @faujong You're welcome. It affects only your Sesion, for all the database to be affected, `alter system` is used and mostly needs restart. I'm editing the answer so that you perform query without function.