# Return time between two dates except weekends

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, recursive-query

I need to return the time between two dates in `Oracle` except the time during the weekends, I could return the minute. But when I set a weekend date, I receive a `null` result instead of the remaining time in workweek.

First, we need to create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_bus_minutes_between (start_dt DATE, end_dt DATE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    v_return NUMBER;
BEGIN
    select  sum(greatest(end_dt - start_dt,0)) * 24 * 60 work_minutes
      into  v_return
      from  dual
      where trunc(start_dt) - trunc(start_dt,'iw') < 5; -- exclude weekends
    RETURN v_return;
END;
```

Case 1 - Return the minutes in the workweek - Ok

Starting and ending in the workweek.

```
SELECT
"GET_BUS_MINUTES_BETWEEN"(TO_DATE('14-09-2020 06:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 
                          TO_DATE('14-09-2020 10:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) "WORK_MINUTES"
FROM
    "SYS"."DUAL";
```

Case 2 - Return the remaining minutes in the workweek - Fail
Starting at the weekend and ending in workweek.

```
SELECT
"GET_BUS_MINUTES_BETWEEN"(TO_DATE('13-09-2020 06:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 
                          TO_DATE('14-09-2020 10:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) "WORK_MINUTES"
FROM
    "SYS"."DUAL";
```

`13-09-2020` is Sunday, therefore I was expected the return as 600 minutes related the Monday.

In these possibilities, we can start at the workweek and end at weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use SQL or a row generator and can do it with a simple calculation using only PL/SQL. Adapted from my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43633234/1509264) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43633234/1509264).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_bus_minutes_between (start_dt DATE, end_dt DATE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  p_start_date   DATE;
  p_end_date     DATE;
  p_working_days NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF start_dt IS NULL OR end_dt IS NULL THEN
    RETURN NUll;
  END IF;

  -- Enforce that the values are earliest start date to latest end date.
  p_start_date := LEAST( start_dt, end_dt );
  p_end_date   := GREATEST( start_dt, end_dt );

  -- Calculate the number of days from the beginning of the ISO week containing
  -- the start date and the beginning of the ISO week containing the end date
  -- and then multiply this by 5/7 to get the number of full business days.
  --
  -- Then add on the extra days from the beginining of the ISO week containing
  -- the end date and the end date and subtract the extra days from the
  -- beginning of the ISO week containing the start date to the start date.
  p_working_days := ( TRUNC( p_end_date, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( p_start_date, 'IW' ) ) * 5 / 7
                    + LEAST( p_end_date - TRUNC( p_end_date, 'IW' ), 5 )
                    - LEAST( p_start_date - TRUNC( p_start_date, 'IW' ), 5 );

  -- If the start date and end date are reversed then return a negative value.
  IF start_dt > end_dt THEN
    RETURN -ROUND( p_working_days * 24 * 60, 3 );
  ELSE
    RETURN +ROUND( p_working_days * 24 * 60, 3 );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT GET_BUS_MINUTES_BETWEEN(
         DATE '2020-09-14' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, 
         DATE '2020-09-14' + INTERVAL '10' HOUR
       ) AS minutes_between
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | MINUTES_BETWEEN |
> | --------------: |
> |             240 |
> ```

and:

```sql
SELECT GET_BUS_MINUTES_BETWEEN(
         DATE '2020-09-13' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, 
         DATE '2020-09-14' + INTERVAL '10' HOUR
       ) AS minutes_between
FROM   DUAL;
```

outputs:

> ```
> | MINUTES_BETWEEN |
> | --------------: |
> |             600 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2c5bfaa783152d6c37e46a9de5a09fa9)*

Answer (score 1):

If the intervals are not too big, one method uses a brute force approach to generate all minutes in the range, then exclude week-ends:

```
with cte(dt, end_dt) as (
    select start_dt, end_dt from dual
    union all
    select dt + 1 / 24 / 60, end_dt from cte where dt < end_dt
)
select count(*) work_minutes
from cte
where trunc(dt) - trunc(dt,'iw') < 5
```

If the intervals are not too big, one method uses a brute force approach to generate all minutes in the range, then exclude week-ends:

```
with cte(dt, end_dt) as (
    select start_dt, end_dt from dual
    union all
    select dt + 1 / 24 / 60, end_dt from cte where dt < end_dt
)
select count(*) work_minutes
from cte
where to_char(dt, 'IW') <= 5
```

If you have large intervals, we can reduce the number of iterations by pre-generating minutes / hours series:

```
with 
    params (start_dt, end_dt) as (
        select start_dt, end_dt from dual
    )
    minutes (mi) as (
        select 0 from dual
        union all select mi + 1 from minutes where mi < 59
    ),
    hours (hr) as (
        select 0 from dual
        union all select hr + 1 from hours where hr < 23
    )
select count(*) work_minutes
from params p
cross join minutes m
cross join hours h
where 
    p.start_dt + h.hr / 24 + m.mi / 24 / 60 <= end_dt
    and trunc(p.start_dt + h.hr / 24 + m.mi / 24 / 60) - trunc(p.start_dt + h.hr / 24 + m.mi / 24 / 60,'iw') < 5
```

Comment: Hey @GMB, nice solution!
I'm testing from `13-09-2020...` up to `14-09-2020` and the function is returning 0.
`SELECT
    "RAFAEL_LIMA"."GET_BUS_MINUTES_BETWEEN"(TO_DATE('13-09-2020 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 
                                            TO_DATE('14-09-2020 12:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) "WORK_MINUTES"
FROM
    "SYS"."DUAL";
    `