# Incorrect day of the week in Oracle Function

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have this common function which counts business days between two dates.

```
BUS_DAY := TRUNC(TO_DATE(P_START_DATE, D_FORMAT));
DATES_DIFF := TRUNC(TO_DATE(P_END_DATE, D_FORMAT)) - BUS_DAY;

  SELECT MAX(RNUM) INTO T_DAYS
    FROM (
      SELECT ROWNUM RNUM
      FROM ALL_OBJECTS
    )
   WHERE ROWNUM <= DATES_DIFF
      AND TO_CHAR(BUS_DAY + RNUM, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN');
```

My problem is it gives an incorrect day of the week for dates.
For example, today is Oct 7 2020 WEDNESDAY, but the function reads this date as a MONDAY, so it gives incorrect number of business days T_T
Anyone have the same issue or have any idea why oracle is reading dates incorrectly?

Comment: What does the clock on database server say? Which date is it there?

Comment: What about public holidays, e.g. New-Year?

Comment: What data type is `p_start_date`?  If that is a `date` then passing it to `to_date()` is a bug. If it's a varchar, it should be a `date` (and then you can remove the `to_date()`  call.

Comment: At a guess, your `p_start_date` and `p_end_date` are already dates, and so using `to_date()` is a bug, as already said. If your NLS settings have YY or RR and `d_format` is using YYYY then today's date would end up as 0020-10-07, which was a Monday.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the value without having to use a row generator and independent of the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`.

Adapted from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43633234/1509264) (which is the same problem but also ignoring holidays):

- Get the number of days between the Mondays of both weeks (using `TRUNC( datevalue, 'IW' )` as an `NLS_LANGUAGE` independent method of finding the Monday of the week) and multiply by <sup>5</sup>/<sub>7</sub> to give the week days of the full weeks; then
- Add the day of the week (Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, etc., to a maximum of 5 to ignore weekends) to count the part week for the end date; and
- Subtract the day of the week of the start date to remove the counted values beforehand.

Like this:

```sql
SELECT ( TRUNC( end_date, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) ) * 5 / 7
       + LEAST( end_date - TRUNC( end_date, 'IW' ) + 1, 5 )
       - LEAST( start_date - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) + 1, 5 )
         AS WeekDaysDifference
FROM   your_table
```

If you are just calculating for a single value in a function then you can avoid a context-switch to SQL and do it all in PL/SQL:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION count_weekdays_between(
  p_start_date IN DATE,
  p_end_date   IN DATE
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN ( TRUNC( p_end_date, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( p_start_date, 'IW' ) ) * 5 / 7
         + LEAST( p_end_date - TRUNC( p_end_date, 'IW' ) + 1, 5 )
         - LEAST( p_start_date - TRUNC( p_start_date, 'IW' ) + 1, 5 );
END;
/
```

and:

```sql
SELECT count_weekdays_between( DATE '2020-09-29', DATE '2020-10-07' )
         AS num_week_days
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs: `6`

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=58b46d37f146fe5160d562d6b152c226)*

Answer (score 1):

Using `SELECT ... FROM ALL_OBJECTS` is a really ugly workaround.

What about this proposal?

```
DECLARE

    BUS_DAY DATE := TRUNC(SYSDATE - 10);
    DATES_DIFF INTEGER := TRUNC(SYSDATE - BUS_DAY);
    T_DAYS INTEGER;

BEGIN

    SELECT SUM(1)
    INTO T_DAYS
    FROM dual
    WHERE TO_CHAR(BUS_DAY + LEVEL, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= DATES_DIFF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'T_DAYS = ' || T_DAYS );

END;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. May I know why using ALL_OBJECTS is a dirty workaround? But I will consider this approach.

Comment: Using `CONNECT BY` is much more efficient. And at least in theory the view may have less rows than the number of required days.

Answer (score 1):

Looking just at why you see Monday, and ignoring whether this is a good approach - which @MTO has covered - then if `p_start_date` and `p_end_date` are dates, using `to_date()` on them is a bug, as @a_horse_with_no_name said in a comment.

If your NLS settings have YY or RR and `d_format` is using YYYY then today's date would end up as 0020-10-07, which was a Monday.

As a demo:

```
declare
  P_START_DATE date := date '2020-10-07';
  D_FORMAT varchar2(11) := 'DD-MON-YYYY';
  BUS_DAY date;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(P_START_DATE || ' => ' || to_char(P_START_DATE, 'SYYYY-MM-DD Day'));
  BUS_DAY := TRUNC(TO_DATE(P_START_DATE, D_FORMAT));
  dbms_output.put_line(BUS_DAY || ' => ' || to_char(BUS_DAY, 'SYYYY-MM-DD Day'));
end;
/

07-OCT-20 =>  2020-10-07 Wednesday
07-OCT-20 =>  0020-10-07 Monday
```

When you do:

```
BUS_DAY := TRUNC(TO_DATE(P_START_DATE, D_FORMAT));
```

it's really:

```
BUS_DAY := TRUNC(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(P_START_DATE), D_FORMAT));
```

and that implicit `TO_CHAR(P_START_DATE)` is using your NLS settings, so it's something like:

```
BUS_DAY := TRUNC(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(P_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-RR'), D_FORMAT));
```

You end up with that intermediate string value as `'07-OCT-20'`. If you convert that back to a date with a YYYY year component in the format mask then the year is seen as 0020, not 2020:

```
select to_char(to_date('07-OCT-20', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YYYY') from dual;

07-OCT-0020
```

You don't need to convert to and from a string, and you're already truncating to set any time part to midnight, so you only need that part:

```
BUS_DAY := TRUNC(P_START_DATE);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=430e1e68a6c7088f2610b7f9a3d0ca04)

Some clients use their own display preferences rather than NLS settings, so you may be seeing the date as 07-Oct-2020 when you query, while the NLS setting has YY or RR. You can query `nls_session_parameters` to check.

Comment: This answer really enlightened me on the date formatting features of Oracle. Thank you so much. Also, thank you for providing such detailed explanation.