# how to check how many Sunday is present between two dates in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

**I want to check the number of 'Sundays' present between 2 dates

example,**

**CREATED_DATE** 21-10-23 06:00:00.000000000 PM  <kbd>SATURDAY</kbd>

**UPDATED_DATE** 23-10-23 06:00:00.000000000 PM <kbd>MONDAY</kbd>

I want to see how many 'Sundays' are there in between, in this case **1**

this is my code, the case statement is to be focused,

```
SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (UPDATEDDATE - CREATEDDATE)) <= 4   -- hours should be < or = to 4
        AND (
            EXTRACT(DAY FROM (UPDATEDDATE - CREATEDDATE)) -        -- days in between
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM DUAL
                WHERE TO_CHAR(CREATEDDATE + LEVEL, 'D') = '1'      -- is sunday?
                CONNECT BY CREATEDDATE + LEVEL <= UPDATEDDATE      -- checking till the end date
            ) = 0
        )
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
) AS "0_4",
```

I have 2 columns

CREATEDDATE  -> 04-11-23 06:00:00.000000000 PM <kbd>saturday</kbd>

UPDATEDDATE -> 04-11-23 08:00:00.000000000 PM <kbd>saturday</kbd>

I want to check if the hours between the dates is less than 4 or equal and the days between it has 'Sundays', if there is any Sunday I want the count of how many 'Sundays' present and substract if from the number of days between the both dates,

in this case, the hours between 2 dates is,

```
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (UPDATEDDATE - CREATEDDATE)) -- 2hrs
```

and days between 2 dates is,

```
EXTRACT(DAY FROM (UPDATEDDATE - CREATEDDATE)) -- 0 days
```

here the condition is not satisfying, and also if there are sundays in between, it is not working, is the code logic is correct or not?, need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use a row generator to find all the days and can calculate the number of Sundays using the ISO weeks (which is independent of any language or territory settings that you may be using):

```sql
SELECT created_date,
       updated_date,
       -- Number of Sundays in the start week
       CASE
       WHEN TRUNC(created_date) - TRUNC(created_date, 'IW') <= 6 -- Sunday
       THEN 1
       END
       +
       -- Number of full weeks
       (TRUNC(updated_date, 'IW') - TRUNC(created_date, 'IW')) / 7
       -- Do not double count the first week
       - 1
       +
       -- Number of Sundays in the end week
       CASE
       WHEN TRUNC(updated_date) - TRUNC(updated_date, 'IW') < 6 -- Sunday
       THEN 0
       ELSE 1
       END
       AS number_of_sundays
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (created_date, updated_date) AS
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2023-10-21 18:00:00.000000000',
         TIMESTAMP '2023-10-23 20:00:00.000000000'
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2023-10-21 20:00:00.000000000',
         TIMESTAMP '2023-10-22 04:00:00.000000000'
  FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CREATED_DATE | UPDATED_DATE | NUMBER_OF_SUNDAYS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-21 18:00:00.000000000 | 2023-10-23 20:00:00.000000000 | 1 |
| 2023-10-21 20:00:00.000000000 | 2023-10-22 04:00:00.000000000 | 1 |

---

If you want to find the difference between two timestamps excluding Sundays then you also need to consider that you may not have a complete Sunday period and can use:

```sql
SELECT created_date,
       updated_date,
       updated_date
       - created_date
       - (
           -- Time on Sundays in the start week
           LEAST(
             TRUNC(created_date, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY - created_date,
             INTERVAL '1' DAY
           )
           +
           -- Sundays in the full weeks
           (
             TRUNC(updated_date, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY - TRUNC(created_date, 'IW')
           ) / 7 * INTERVAL '1' DAY
           +
           -- Time on Sunday in the last week
           GREATEST(
             updated_date - TRUNC(updated_date, 'IW') - INTERVAL '6' DAY,
             INTERVAL '0' DAY
           )
         )
       AS time_difference_exclude_sunday
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| CREATED_DATE | UPDATED_DATE | TIME_DIFFERENCE_EXCLUDE_SUNDAY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-21 18:00:00.000000000 | 2023-10-23 20:00:00.000000000 | +000000001 02:00:00.000000000 |
| 2023-10-21 20:00:00.000000000 | 2023-10-22 04:00:00.000000000 | +000000000 04:00:00.000000000 |

---

If you want to filter the rows to only show those when there are 4 or less hours between the created and updated times then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  updated_date
       - created_date
       - (
           -- Time on Sundays in the start week
           LEAST(
             TRUNC(created_date, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY - created_date,
             INTERVAL '1' DAY
           )
           +
           -- Sundays in the full weeks
           (
             TRUNC(updated_date, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY - TRUNC(created_date, 'IW')
           ) / 7 * INTERVAL '1' DAY
           +
           -- Time on Sunday in the last week
           GREATEST(
             updated_date - TRUNC(updated_date, 'IW') - INTERVAL '6' DAY,
             INTERVAL '0' DAY
           )
         )
      <= INTERVAL '4' HOUR;
```

Outputs:

| CREATED_DATE | UPDATED_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-21 20:00:00.000000000 | 2023-10-22 04:00:00.000000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/agxYrp5z)

---

As for your question

> is the code logic is correct or not?

No, it is not.

If you have the dates `'2023-10-21 20:00:00.000000000'` and `'2023-10-22 00:00:00.000000000'` so that the last day is a Sunday and the time component of `updated_date` is earlier in the day than the time component of the `created_date` then the check `CREATEDDATE + LEVEL <= UPDATEDDATE` will skip the final Sunday.

It also does not consider fractions of Sundays.

Comment: sir logic was right, but i'm ashamed to say its difficult to grasp the logic well, i also want to exclude the saturdays and list of particular days ( example public holidays like christmas) and exclude those days between the createddate and updateddate and give out the remaining time, i tried so many ways, but still stuck with wrong results, will you be able to show how its done sir ?

Comment: @ClintonHadrian See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43633234/1509264